# Mass generation for Z' and W' bosons

Tags: mass, higgs, electroweak, beyond-the-standard-model

I read that some Beyond the Standard Model theories require the existence of additional gauge bosons such as $Z'$ and $W'$. As far as I understood, an extension of the $SU(2)_L$ symmetry is required, that is the right handed $SU(2)_R$. My question is how do $Z'$ and
$W'$ acquire a mass? In other words, do these models need to alter the electroweak symmetry breaking mechanism in a significant way?

Comment: What do you mean by "in a significant way"? Gauge bosons get mass through symmetry breaking. If you have more gauge bosons, i.e. another symmetry, you need to break it, too. But it's always symmetry breaking, the *mechanism* doesn't change.

Comment: So, you mean nothing changes in the Higgs sector? None of these theories alters the electroweak symmetry breaking mechanism? They predict exactly the same features for the Higgs?

Comment: I think you just get "another" Higgs from breaking the $\mathrm{SU}(2)_L$, and probably their mass or other properties would also change, but the *mechanism* (about which you asked) stays the same.